# Change of variable formula given a variable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, distributions

I know the current value of $\lambda_{11}$ and I wish to calculate the probability of $\lambda_{12},\lambda_{22}$ which, are generated as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\mu\sim & \,U(0,1)\\
\lambda_{12}=&\lambda_{11}\frac{\mu}{1-\mu}\\
\lambda_{22}=&\lambda_{11}\frac{1-\mu}{\mu}
\end{align}
$$

Using the change of variable formula I believe that $p(\lambda_{12},\lambda_{22})=p(\mu)p(\lambda_{11})|J|$ where $J$ is the jacobian, $\frac{\partial(\lambda_{11},\mu_1)}{\partial(\lambda_{12},\lambda_{22})}$ and 
\begin{align}
J^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\mu_1}{1-\mu_1} & \lambda_{11}\frac{1}{(1-\mu_1)^2}\\
\frac{1-\mu_1}{\mu_1} & -\lambda_{11}\frac{1}{\mu_1^2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Thus, $|J|=\frac{\mu_1(1-\mu_1)}{2\lambda_{11}}$. Considering that $p(\mu)=1$,
$$
p(\lambda_{12},\lambda_{22})=\frac{\mu_1(1-\mu_1)}{2\lambda_{11}}p(\lambda_{11})
$$

However, I need to find $p(\lambda_{12},\lambda_{22}|\lambda_{11})$. My question is why is this not simply **one** which is the probability of $p(\mu)$. $\lambda_{12},\lambda_{22}$ are only dependant on $\mu$ given $\lambda_{11}$.

Comment: You seem to be treating $\lambda_{11}$ sometimes as a constant and sometimes as a random variable, bivariately distributed with $\mu$. Which is it? If it's a random variable, then what is the bivariate distribution of $\lambda_{11},\mu$? And if it's not a random variable, then why are you including it in the Jacobian?

Comment: To give you some context I'm trying to do Reversible Jump MCMC. So basically I generate $\lambda_{11}$ first and then calculate $\lambda_{12},\lambda_{22}$. So I suppose until the last two lines I assume randomness. But the **given** $\lambda_{11}$ case is what I'm interested in.